# Fetching and updating data from External system in salesforce via webservie callout

Tags: integration, salesforce-id

Is it possible to perform update on the fetched data from external system without SAVING the same in salesforce and sending the updates back to the external system by using web service callout?

Comment: short answer is yes but what do you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as you can stay within the [Callout Limits and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm).

Generally that means making fewer than 100 callouts and staying within the 120 second cumulative callout timeout.

So within one Apex transaction you can retrieve data via a callout, modify it, and then make another callout to update it.

You would also need to stay within the Apex CPU and heap size limits.

Comment: Hi Daniel...Thanks for your response...let me tell you my requirement here. In salesforce user will fetch customer data  related to a case from external system

Comment: The fetched data will be shown to the user in a visualforce page without saving it in salesforce database. Upto now all is ok and working. Now user will update the same customer record if required and the update should sync back to the external system. Is it possible to update the customer record and sync it to external system without saving it in salesfroce database in some form (Some stub object records which will be deleted after syncing)? Lightning connect is out of scope here.

Comment: @Montosh Yes, that would be possible. Just keep the records for the Visualforce page in [View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State). Then you can make callouts as required to sync back to the external system.